# Seaborn boxplot quartile calculation

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn

i am using seaborn version 0.7.1 for python. I am trying to create a boxplot for the below numpy array

```
arr = np.array([2, 4, 5, 5, 8, 8, 9])
```

from my understanding the Quartiles Q1 and Q3 should be 4 and 8 but from the boxplot generated the Q1 is approximately 4.5. What am i missing ?

i am using the follwing command to generate the chart

```
sns.boxplot(arr)
```

[image]

Comment: As you don't have exact 25% percentile in the array (7 items), it's calculated as an average of two elements equally close to 25%: 4 and 5, yielding 4.5.

Comment: I do think the seaborn boxplot is missing some critical documentation - it should at the very least include a link to an explanation of the underlying method used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would of course depend on the definition of a quartile.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile) mentions 3 methods to calculate the quartile,

- method1: Take median of the lower part of the sample [2,4,5]. Result 4.
- method2: Take median of the lower part of the sample (including its median) [2,4,5,5]. Result 4.5.
- method3: The lower quartile is 75% of the second data value plus 25% of the third data value. Result: 4*0.75+5*0.25 = 4.25. (It's always the mean between method1 and 2.

You may also use numpy to calculate the quartiles

```
x = [2, 4, 5, 5, 8, 8, 9]
np.percentile(x, [25])
```

This returns `4.5`

Comment: Thanks a lot, i did not know about these methods of calculating quartiles.