# Problem overlaying additional percentile markers on seaborn boxplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, boxplot

I want to plot additional markers on a boxplot to show 95th and 5th percentiles. I want the whiskers to show 90th and 10th percentiles which I believe I can do with whis = [10,95]

To test this is working correctly I set both my markers and my whiskers to 5 and 95.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

assay=pd.read_csv('df.csv')

#obtain percentiles of interest
pcntls=assay.groupby(['STRAT']).describe(percentiles=[0.05,0.95])
sumry= pcntls['Total'].T



#plot boxplot (with whiskers set to 5 and 95 as well to check)
ax=sns.boxplot(x=assay['STRAT'],y=assay["Total"], whis=[5,95],data=assay, showfliers=False,color='lightblue', 
            showmeans=True,meanprops={"marker":"s","markersize":10,"markerfacecolor":"white", "markeredgecolor":"grey"})
plt.axhline(0.30, color='green',linestyle='dashed', label="0.3% S")
#ax.set_yscale('log')
leg= plt.legend()
plt.title("Assay data")


#overlay additional percentile points ( same as whiskers to check)
ax.scatter(x=list(sumry.columns.values),y=sumry.loc['5%'])
ax.scatter(x=list(sumry.columns.values),y=sumry.loc['95%'])
```

Which gives me:

[image]

The two plots furthest to the right have the markers applied incorrectly (the markers should be at the same y values as the ends of the whiskers), the order of the data series seems to have these reversed; but also, the percentiles seem off, the whiskers and markers will not match up even if the correct sequence is applied. Any ideas whats wrong and how to fix this?

Data below.

```
From    To  Interval (m)    Class   STRAT   Total
308 309 1   PAF CBC 4.15
309 310 1   PAF CBC 3.76
320 321 1   PAF-LC  CBC 0.85
330 331 1   PAF-LC  CBC 0.698
342 343 1   NAF LBB 0.259
376 377 1   NAF LBB 0.395
412 413 1   PAF-LC  LBB 1.19
51  52  1   PAF UBB 0.1
420 420.5   0.5 PAF-LC  UAB 1
189 190 1   PAF LBB 1.52
520 521 1   NAF UAB 3
632 633 1   NAF UAB 0.0615
644 645 1   NAF-AC  UAB 0.178
308 309 1   PAF CBC 4.15
309 310 1   PAF CBC 3.76
320 321 1   PAF-LC  CBC 0.85
330 331 1   PAF-LC  CBC 0.698
342 343 1   NAF-AC  LBB 0.259
376 377 1   NAF-AC  LBB 0.395
412 413 1   PAF-LC  LBB 1.19
51  52  1   PAF UBB 2.27
420 420.5   0.5 PAF-LC  UAB 1
189 190 1   PAF LBB 1.52
520 521 1   NAF-AC  UAB 1
632 633 1   NAF-AC  UAB 0.0615
644 645 1   NAF-AC  UAB 0.178
308 309 1   PAF CBC 4.15
309 310 1   PAF CBC 3.76
320 321 1   PAF-LC  CBC 0.85
330 331 1   PAF-LC  CBC 0.698
342 343 1   NAF-AC  LBB 0.259
376 377 1   NAF-AC  LBB 0.395
412 413 1   PAF-LC  LBB 1.19
51  52  1   PAF UBB 2.27
420 420.5   0.5 PAF-LC  UAB 0.002
189 190 1   PAF LBB 1.52
520 521 1   NAF-HS  UAB 1.45
632 633 1   NAF-HS  UAB 0.0615
644 645 1   NAF-HS  UAB 0.178
308 309 1   PAF CBC 4.15
309 310 1   PAF CBC 3.76
320 321 1   PAF-LC  CBC 0.85
330 331 1   PAF-LC  CBC 0.698
342 343 1   NAF-HS  LBB 0.259
376 377 1   NAF-HS  LBB 0.395
412 413 1   PAF-LC  LBB 1.19
51  52  1   PAF UBB 3
420 420.5   0.5 PAF-LC  UAB 1
189 190 1   PAF LBB 1.52
520 521 1   NAF-HS  UAB 1.45
632 633 1   NAF-HS  UAB 0.0615
644 645 1   NAF-HS  UAB 0.178
51  52  1   PAF UBB 0.1
51  52  1   PAF UBB 0.2
51  52  1   PAF UBB 2.27
51  52  1   PAF UBB 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply sort the boxplot data using:

```py
ordered=sorted(assay['STRAT'].unique())
```

and do the same for the percentile data:

```py
ax.scatter(x=sorted(list(sumry.columns.values)),y=sumry.loc['5%'])
ax.scatter(x=sorted(list(sumry.columns.values)),y=sumry.loc['95%'])
```

plus some gridlines, giving:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

assay=pd.read_csv('df.csv')

#obtain percentiles of interest
pcntls=assay.groupby(['STRAT']).describe(percentiles=[0.05,0.95])
sumry= pcntls['Total'].T

ordered=sorted(assay['STRAT'].unique())

#plot boxplot (with whiskers set to 5 and 95 as well to check)
ax=sns.boxplot(x=assay['STRAT'],y=assay["Total"], order=ordered,whis=[5,95],data=assay, showfliers=False,color='lightblue', 
            showmeans=True,meanprops={"marker":"s","markersize":10,"markerfacecolor":"white", "markeredgecolor":"grey"})
plt.axhline(0.30, color='green',linestyle='dashed', label="0.3% S")
#ax.set_yscale('log')
leg= plt.legend()
plt.title("Assay data")

plt.grid(True, which='both')

#overlay additional percentile points ( same as whiskers to check)
ax.scatter(x=sorted(list(sumry.columns.values)),y=sumry.loc['5%'])
ax.scatter(x=sorted(list(sumry.columns.values)),y=sumry.loc['95%'])
```

results in correct output order, but there is a discrepency with the calculation of the 95th percentile for UAB, likely due to multiple methods and the small dataset. e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50585013/seaborn-boxplot-quartile-calculation)
[image]